# Transforming a vector of month numbers

Tags: r, vector, diff

The following vector contains month numbers.

```
x <- c(10,4,10,12,1,3,6,7,9,11,12,4,7,8)
```

Specifically, the first element is the 10th month of some year, the second is the 4th month of the next year, etc.
I am looking for a way to add 12 in the elements of x, where needed, so that I get a vector y like this:

```
y <- c(10,16,22,24,25,27,30,31,33,35,36,40,43,44)
```

How would you suggest to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can compare the adjacent elements with `diff`, check whether it is less than 0 to create a logical vector, concatenate with `FALSE` to account for the length difference in output of `diff`, get the `cumsum`, multiply by 12 and add to x

```
x+ cumsum(c(FALSE, diff(x)< 0)) *12
#[1] 10 16 22 24 25 27 30 31 33 35 36 40 43 44
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the example you provided, I'd iterate through the list of elements and whenever I see an element that is smaller than the previous one, add n*12 to the following ones. Where n = 0 initially and incremented each time you detect a smaller number than the previous one in the list.

My question is, though, how you handle when you need the 2nd month from a certain year and nothing more from that one, but the 7th month for example from the following year? You'll definitely need something to differentiate this case from the case when you have the 2nd month and the 7th month from the same year. The simple list of numbers is not enough for that I'm afraid.

Comment: You are right. A second vector of years is needed. There is where the comparison of adjacent elements must be done.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13429777)

Comment: @user2100721: I don't agree. I tried to explain one way how I would solve a problem in my 1st paragraph. This was not in code, but still, I think an explanation of my solution. In the second paragraph, I mentioned one flaw of that concept and a problem, that I thought will prevent any correct solution if we have only the provided data as the input. In my opinion, this is also helpful information to finally be able to come up with a really working solution for someone.